# Конвертация в JSON

Tags: json, xml

Представьте XML-записку в формате JSON

```
<note>
   <to>John</to>
   <from>Smith</from>
   <heading>Meeting</heading>
   <body>Let us meet tommorow</body>
</note>
```

Корректным по форме, но но не по содержанию является ответ

{"to":0}

подскажите, какой ответ.

Comment: https://ibb.co/F76BPVd  вот так примерно - проверил на валидность

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете положиться на онлайн-сервис.
Например, вы можете попробовать:
https://convertxmljson.com/

Comment: Переведите ваш ответ на русский язык.